# iOS run 3.5 inch app on 4 inch device

Tags: ios

Is there a way let my app always run as 3.5 inch screen even on 4 inch device?

I saw some apps did that. When running on 4 inch device, those apps does not fill the whole screen and show in the middle of the screen.

The reason I want to do this because currently our UI team only have design for 3.5 inch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete Default-568h@2x.png image (with dimensions of 640X1136 pixels) file in your Resources or Resources/iphone folders and you should be good.